# How can I get the rotation the image will be in relative to the device's base orientation with the camera dart package?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, image-rotation

I am using [Dart's `camera` package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) to capture images from the device's camera. When capturing an image with

```dart
await cameraController.startImageStream((CameraImage cameraImage) async {
    await cameraController.stopImageStream();
    /* ... */
});
```

it arrives in an orientation that is not upright. I am currently rotating the image by a hardcoded amount, however, this is not consistent across cameras even on the same device.

I tried looking through the source code of `camera`, but I found no obvious variable or function from which I could retrieve such an offset.